# Showing/Hiding Div in response to different sized screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked for an answer to this question but I haven't found precisely what I was looking for.

I'm trying to switch divs depending on the size of the screen that my site is displayed on.

At full size (ex. a computer monitor), my div will display a .png file, but when the screen size shrinks to a mobile sized port, I want it to display another div with a series of .png files in a row.

The code currently looks like this if it helps with clarity:

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
  <div class="slide">
    <img id="logo" src="img/TestImageA.png">
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <img id="logo" src="img/TestImageB.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 
  <div class="section" id="section1-mobile">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="customer-container-1">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Customer_1.png">
      </div>
      <div class="customer-container-2">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Customer_2.png">
      </div>
      <div class="customer-container-3"">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Customer_3.png">
      </div>
      <div class="customer-container-4">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Customer_4.png">
      </div>
      <div class="customer-container-5">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Customer_5.png">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="inventory-container-1">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Inventory_1.png">
      </div>
      <div class="inventory-container-2">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Inventory_2.png">
      </div>
      <div class="inventory-container-3">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Inventory_3.png">
      </div>
      <div class="inventory-container-4">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Inventory_4.png">
      </div>
      <div class="inventory-container-5">
        <img id="logo" src="img/PAGE2_Inventory_5.png">
      </div>
    </div>
</div> 
    -->
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You post doesn't have a clear technical question. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. StackOverflow also has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as a **[media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**. There's a basic tutorial on these provided over [**at W3Schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

In the following example, I use a width of `700px` to invert the display of the DIVs:

```
@media scren and (max-width: 700px) {
  #section1-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  #section1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Mobiles will see `#section1-mobile`, and regular devices will see `#section1`.

Note that media queries will take 'priority' sequentially in the DOM, and you can even **chain** media queries, such as:

```
@media scren and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 600px) { }
```

This will allow you to target very specific sets of devices; just change the pixel values to suit. In fact, there's even some [**pre-defined standards**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) that target common devices that you can use to your advantage!

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks Obsidian! The media queries are helpful, I just think my problem is that it's conflicting with a library that I'm using (fullpage.js) which causes both divs to display after using the media query. So my main issue is to try get the query to work with fullpage.js

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bootstrap for this. Also check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp